# Secrets from GitHub Actions unavailable in the docker container

Tags: python, docker, deployment, github-actions

I was trying to deploy my package, which generates through GitHub Actions and pushes to GitHub Packages.

After that, I try to deploy it on my server, but the environment variables are not added to the container.

Here is my workflow file:

```yaml
# GitHub packages build and push v2
name: Build and Push Docker Image

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/piggybot:latest

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.BOT_TOKEN }}
      POSTGRES_DSN: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_DSN }}
      REDIS_DSN: ${{ secrets.REDIS_DSN }}
      APP_HOST: ${{ secrets.APP_HOST }}
      APP_PORT: ${{ secrets.APP_PORT }}
      WEBHOOK_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.WEBHOOK_DOMAIN }}
      WEBHOOK_PATH: ${{ secrets.WEBHOOK_PATH }}
      ENVIRONMENT: ${{ secrets.ENVIRONMENT }}
      SERVICE_NAME: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_NAME }}
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to VDS
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.SSH_PASS }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}

          script: |
            docker login -u ${{ github.repository_owner }} -p ${{ secrets.TOKEN }} ghcr.io
            docker pull ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/piggybot:latest
            docker stop piggybot
            docker rm piggybot
            docker run -e BOT_TOKEN=$BOT_TOKEN -e POSTGRES_DSN=$POSTGRES_DSN -e REDIS_DSN=$REDIS_DSN -e APP_HOST=$APP_HOST -e APP_PORT=$APP_PORT -e WEBHOOK_DOMAIN=$WEBHOOK_DOMAIN -e WEBHOOK_PATH=$WEBHOOK_PATH -e ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT -e SERVICE_NAME=$SERVICE_NAME -d --name piggybot ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/piggybot:latest
```

That's how I'm trying to get those vars:

```py
class Config(BaseSettings):
    bot_token: str = os.environ["BOT_TOKEN"]
    postgres_dsn: PostgresDsn = os.environ["POSTGRES_DSN"]
    redis_dsn: Optional[RedisDsn] = os.environ["REDIS_DSN"]
    app_host: Optional[str] = os.environ["APP_HOST"]
    app_port: Optional[int] = os.environ["APP_PORT"]
    webhook_domain: Optional[str] = os.environ["WEBHOOK_DOMAIN"]
    webhook_path: Optional[str] = os.environ["WEBHOOK_PATH"]
    environment: Optional[str] = os.environ["ENVIRONMENT"]
    service_name: Optional[str] = os.environ["SERVICE_NAME"]
```

My Dockerfile:

```yaml
# Separate build image
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye as compile-image
RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y gcc \
 && pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
 && pip install --no-cache-dir setuptools wheel \
 && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Final image
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye
COPY --from=compile-image /opt/venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
WORKDIR /app
COPY app /app
CMD ["python", "-m", "tgbot"]
```

docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:

  bot:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    stop_signal: SIGINT
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The problem is that I either don't get the environment variable at all, or it is equal to an empty string

Comment: Move that `env` section under your deploy step. Use `echo $VAR` to debug this first without any other `docker` commands.

Comment: @Azeem But if I move `env` under deploy I won't be able to access the variables because they haven't been declared yet. But I used `echo ${{secrets.BOT_TOKEN}} | sed 's/./& /g'`  and it brought me my token, separated by spaces, so the token is still stored in GitHub Secrets

Comment: `echo` with $VAR` syntax that you're trying to pass to `docker run` with `-e` flag. Try to verify if those values are correct or not. IIUC, that's where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I solved this problem. Now I pass env variables directly to docker run `docker run -e BOT_TOKEN=${{ secrets.BOT_TOKEN }}`

Here is working `publish.yml`:

```yaml
# GitHub packages build and push v2
name: Build and Push Docker Image

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/piggybot:latest

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to VDS
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.SSH_PASS }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}

          script: |
            docker login -u ${{ github.repository_owner }} -p ${{ secrets.TOKEN }} ghcr.io
            docker stop piggybot
            docker rm piggybot
            docker images -a | grep "piggybot" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi
            docker pull ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/piggybot:latest
            docker run -e BOT_TOKEN=${{ secrets.BOT_TOKEN }} -e POSTGRES_DSN=${{ secrets.POSTGRES_DSN }} -e REDIS_DSN=${{ secrets.REDIS_DSN }} -e APP_HOST=${{ secrets.APP_HOST }} -e APP_PORT=${{ secrets.APP_PORT }} -e WEBHOOK_DOMAIN=${{ secrets.WEBHOOK_DOMAIN }} -e WEBHOOK_PATH=${{ secrets.WEBHOOK_PATH }} -e ENVIRONMENT=${{ secrets.ENVIRONMENT }} -e SERVICE_NAME=${{ secrets.SERVICE_NAME }} -d --name piggybot ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/piggybot:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

[applboy/ssh-action](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action) has `envs` as input parameter. I've used this method and it works like a charm! There's some repetition but well I haven't found any alternative yet.

```
# GitHub packages build and push v2
name: Build and Push Docker Image

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/piggybot:latest

deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.BOT_TOKEN }}
      POSTGRES_DSN: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_DSN }}
      REDIS_DSN: ${{ secrets.REDIS_DSN }}
      APP_HOST: ${{ secrets.APP_HOST }}
      APP_PORT: ${{ secrets.APP_PORT }}
      WEBHOOK_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.WEBHOOK_DOMAIN }}
      WEBHOOK_PATH: ${{ secrets.WEBHOOK_PATH }}
      ENVIRONMENT: ${{ secrets.ENVIRONMENT }}
      SERVICE_NAME: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_NAME }}
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to VDS
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.SSH_PASS }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
          envs: |
            BOT_TOKEN,
            POSTGRES_DSN,
            REDIS_DSN,
            APP_HOST,
            APP_PORT,
            WEBHOOK_DOMAIN,
            WEBHOOK_PATH,
            ENVIRONMENT,
            SERVICE_NAME
          script: |
            docker login -u ${{ github.repository_owner }} -p ${{ secrets.TOKEN }} ghcr.io
            docker pull ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/piggybot:latest
            docker stop piggybot
            docker rm piggybot
            docker run -e BOT_TOKEN=$BOT_TOKEN -e POSTGRES_DSN=$POSTGRES_DSN -e REDIS_DSN=$REDIS_DSN -e APP_HOST=$APP_HOST -e APP_PORT=$APP_PORT -e WEBHOOK_DOMAIN=$WEBHOOK_DOMAIN -e WEBHOOK_PATH=$WEBHOOK_PATH -e ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT -e SERVICE_NAME=$SERVICE_NAME -d --name piggybot ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/piggybot:latest
```